# Counting with pandas (two different numbers at the same row)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file concerning fines for wrong parking and it contains month , year , and the reason for the fine. I want to find the top 10  reasons (Error section / main cause) for getting the fines.

Notice that some rows in the `Error section / main cause` column some rows have two different reasons for getting the fine like ( `0401 Parking Prohibited Area failure to comply with a traffic sign ;  2200 Parking next to the marked parking space`
)

The code takes long time to respond and then gives error.(long list)

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv('Parkingfines.csv', parse_dates=True, 
                 index_col="Month of the error", usecols=["Month of the error", 
                 "Year of the error", "Error section / main cause"], 
                 names=["Month of the error", "Year of the error", "Error section / main cause"], header=0)

df = df['Error section / main cause'].agg(['count'])
```

[Link for the csv file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiJ5CewYiXdpbU90-3arcpc2tZ0)

And then draw a graph of the number of fines per month (from January 2014 to latest data). However this part gives ValueError: Unknown string format

```
counts_per_month = df.groupby(by=['Year of the error', 
                                  'Month of the error', ]).agg('count')
counts_per_month.index = pd.to_datetime(
    [' '.join(map(str, col)).strip() for col in counts_per_month.index.values]
)
# flatten multiindex and convert to datetime

counts_per_month.plot()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name)
    408             try:
--> 409                 values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    410                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas\tslib.c:29768)()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-81c15e474539> in <module>()
     50                                   'Month of the error', ]).agg('count')
     51 counts_per_month.index = pd.to_datetime(
---> 52     [' '.join(map(str, col)).strip() for col in counts_per_month.index.values]
     53 )
     54 # flatten multiindex and convert to datetime

C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 else:
     90                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         return wrapper
     93     return _deprecate_kwarg

C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, coerce, unit, infer_datetime_format)
    289                         yearfirst=yearfirst,
    290                         utc=utc, box=box, format=format, exact=exact,
--> 291                         unit=unit, infer_datetime_format=infer_datetime_format)
    292 
    293 

C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, freq, infer_datetime_format)
    425         return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name=arg.name)
    426     elif com.is_list_like(arg):
--> 427         return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format)
    428 
    429     return _convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]

C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name)
    410                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
    411             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 412                 raise e
    413 
    414     if arg is None:

C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name)
    396                     yearfirst=yearfirst,
    397                     freq=freq,
--> 398                     require_iso8601=require_iso8601
    399                 )
    400 

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas\tslib.c:41972)()

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas\tslib.c:41577)()

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.array_to_datetime (pandas\tslib.c:41466)()

pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.parse_datetime_string (pandas\tslib.c:31806)()

C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1162         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1163     else:
-> 1164         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1165 
   1166 

C:\Users\Dream\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    553 
    554         if res is None:
--> 555             raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
    556 
    557         if len(res) == 0:

ValueError: Unknown string format
```

Comment: Looks like you probably want `value_counts()` there instead of `agg()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your file is a bit corrupted: the following two lines should be merged:

```
255121 October;;
255122 ;2014;0701 Parking without p-recognized / p-unit / p-ticket
```

Then your file seem to be Latin-1 encoded. Python 3 assumes by default that all files are UTF-8 and Python 2 assumes they are ASCII, so you have to tell explicitly that your file is Latin-1.

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/dl/parkingfines-2.csv', sep=';', 
                 encoding='latin-1', header=0)
```

Note also that as David Garwin mentioned, your separator is `;`, not `,` (default), so you have to provide it explicitly. No need other parameters you passed to `pd.read_csv`: column names will be obtained from the first line of the file.

Then we have to address an issue that some fines have more than one cause. This can be treated in different ways. For example, we can replace such records with several records (one new record for every cause). This can be done in the following way:

```
# there are rows without causes, let's drop them
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# save index to use it later
df['idx'] = df.index

# find all rows for which cause contains ';' (this means several 
# causes presented)
multiples_mask = df['Error section / main cause'].str.contains(';')
multiples = df[multiples_mask]

# split each cause with ';' as separator
splitted = multiples['Error section / main cause'].str.split(';')

# create new dataframe
duplicated = []
for (i, row), spl in zip(multiples.iterrows(), splitted):
    for cause in spl:
        duplicated.append([row['Month of the error'], 
                           row['Year of the error'],
                           cause.strip(), i])

# combine the part of dataframe that contains only single causes
# with created new dataframe for several causes
df_with_dupes = pd.concat(
    [df[~ multiples_mask],
     pd.DataFrame(duplicated, columns=df.columns)], ignore_index=True)

# sort with idx
df_with_dupes.sort_values(by='idx', inplace=True)
df = df_with_dupes

# drop idx: we do not need it more
df.drop('idx', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Now we can proceed to your problems. As for your first problem, find the most common causes of fines, the following code works:

```
causes_counts = df['Error section / main cause'].value_counts()
causes_counts.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
print(causes_counts.head(10))
```

As JohnE mentioned in the comment, you have to use `value_counts()` instead of `agg()`. Note also that in your code you tried to replace all the dataframe with the result of this command (`df = df['Error section / main cause'].agg(['count'])` means *replace `df` with the result of calculation of the right hand side*). It is clear that after you did that you lost your initial dataframe and therefore were not able to access it in the following line. So I used different variable name to store the result of counts.

As for your second problem, the following code works:

```
counts_per_month = df.groupby(by=['Year of the error', 
                                  'Month of the error', ]).agg('count')
counts_per_month.index = pd.to_datetime(
    [' '.join(map(str, col)).strip() for col in counts_per_month.index.values]
)
# flatten multiindex and convert to datetime

counts_per_month.plot()
```

[image: counts]

Comment: Thank you Ilya V. Schurov,  without your clarification it would be really impossible to solve these issues (y)

Comment: Does the encoding='latin-1 change if i change the csv file to the German  or the Swedish version ? because the code works very well with the other langauges but without reading some charcaters (ä ö å) :)

Comment: The second code gives this error ValueError: Unknown string format.

Comment: `encoding` depends on encoding of your files. You can try e.g. this service to detect the encoding: https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/

Comment: As for the error, could you please clarify, which part of the code do you mean and provide full traceback? What data do you use — the same as in the example or different?

Comment: I edited the main post with full information concerning the error(ValueError: Unknown string format).

Comment: This probably means that `dateutil.parser.parse` cannot decode strings like `2014 April` to date format. You can remove line `counts_per_month.index = pd.to_datetime([' '.join(map(str, col)).strip() for col in counts_per_month.index.values])` (the image will be a bit less pretty) or tweak it in order to make `parser.parse` happy. It is also possible that updating your Python installation can help.

Comment: Unfortunately, after i deleted the mentioned line it shows only: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x880f610> .However thanks for your attempt to help :)

Comment: If you are working in Jupyter, you have to use `%matplotlib inline` magical command to turn on inline matplotlib plots.

Comment: I just saw your comment, 5 sec ago i figured out that %matplotlib inline was the issue. Thanks a lot, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This line overwrites df

```
 df = df['Error section / main cause'].agg(['count'])
```

This line takes one column and groups it.

```
 df = df['Month of the error'].groupby(df['Year of the error']).agg(['count'])
```

Top 10 reasons should be:

```
 df.reasons.value_counts()
```

number fines per month should be:

```
 df.groupby("month").size()
```